# How to make a scroll view of 9 images in a forEach loop open on image 6 if image 6 is clicked on from a grid?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a grid of images in my app which will open a scroll view of the images if one is clicked. But no matter what image I click, the scroll view will always open on image 1 with 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 below it. I want to make it so if a user clicks on image 6 it will open the scroll view on image 6 with images 1,2,3,4,5 above it and 7,8,9 below it. Here is my code:

```swift
LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, alignment: .center) {
    ForEach(viewModel.posts) { post in
        NavigationLink(destination: ScrollPostView(user: user, postids: viewModel.posts, selectedpostid: post.id)){
            KFImage(URL(string: post.imageurl))
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .cornerRadius(15)
        }
        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 14)
            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2))
     }
}
```

```swift
// scroll view

    @StateObject var viewModel: PostGridViewModel
    let postids: [Post]
    let selectedpostid: Post.ID
    @State private var scrollPosition: Post.ID?

    
    let user: User

    init(user: User, postids: [Post], selectedpostid: Post.ID ) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: PostGridViewModel(user: user))
        self.user = user
        self.postids = postids
        self.selectedpostid = selectedpostid
    }


    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            Color(red: 0.1608, green: 0.4078, blue: 0.3725)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack(spacing: 2){
                ScrollView{
                    
                    VStack{                            
                        ForEach(viewModel.posts) {post in
                            posts_cell(post: post, user: user)
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .padding(.bottom,18)
                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                }
                .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition, anchor: .center)
                .onAppear {
                    scrollPosition = selectedpostid
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                .padding(.top, 30)
                .padding(.bottom, 52)
            }
        }
    }
}

//viewModel
class PostGridViewModel: ObservableObject{
    private let user: User
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    
    
    init(user: User) {
        self.user = user
        
        Task { try await fetchUserPosts() }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchUserPosts() async throws {
        self.posts = try await PostService.FetchUserPosts(uid: user.id)
        
        for i in 0 ..< posts.count {
            posts[i].user = self.user
            
        }
    }
}

//post service
static func FetchUserPosts(uid: String) async throws -> [Post] {
    let snapshot = try await postsCollection.whereField("ownerUid", isEqualTo: uid).order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).getDocuments()
    return try snapshot.documents.compactMap({ try $0.data(as: Post.self) })
}

struct Post: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {

    let id: String
    let ownerUid: String
    let caption: String
    var likes: Int
    var postlikes: Array<String>
    var postsaves: Array<String>
    let imageurl: String
    let timestamp: Timestamp
    var user: User?
    
    var didLike: Bool? = false
    var didSave: Bool? = false
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the index of the tapped element somehow. It's hard to give anything more precise since we don't know the relation between `viewModel.posts` and `user` but a good starting point could be : `ForEach(Array(viewModel.posts.enumerated()), id: \.element) { element, offset in ` and then pass that `offset` to `ScrollPostView` so it knows on which view to start.

There you may need to use `ScrollViewReader` to scroll to that actual element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scroll to a particular view in a `ScrollView` by using its id. This can either be done using a `ScrollViewReader` (as suggested in a comment) or by using a `.scrollPosition` modifier on the `ScrollView` (requires iOS 17).

Here is an example of how it can be done using `.scrollPosition`.

- The images used here are just system images (symbols). The symbol name is used as its id.
- The images in the scrolled view all have different heights. This makes it difficult for a `LazyVStack` to predict the scroll distance correctly, so a `VStack` is used instead. But if your images all have the same height then you could try using a `LazyVStack`.
- Set the target to scroll to in `.onAppear`.
- If you use `.center` as the anchor for scrolling then images in the middle of the list should be centered vertically in the display.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    private let imageNames = ["hare", "tortoise", "dog", "cat", "lizard", "bird", "ant", "ladybug", "fossil.shell", "fish"]
    private let threeColumnGrid: [GridItem] = [.init(), .init(), .init()]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: threeColumnGrid, alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(imageNames, id: \.self) { imageName in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ScrollPostView(imageNames: imageNames, selectedName: imageName)){
                        Image(systemName: imageName)
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .padding()
                            .frame(maxHeight: 100)
                            .background(.yellow)
                            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                    }
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ScrollPostView: View {
    let imageNames: [String]
    let selectedName: String
    @State private var scrollPosition: String?

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(imageNames, id: \.self) { imageName in
                    Image(systemName: imageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .padding()
                        .background(selectedName == imageName ? .orange : .yellow)
                        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        .scrollPosition(id: $scrollPosition, anchor: .center)
        .onAppear {
            scrollPosition = selectedName
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

---

*EDIT* Thanks for updating your question with more code. It looks like everything is correctly in place, but I am wondering if the posts are being loaded after the view has appeared? This might be why the scroll position isn't working.

You could try setting `scrollPosition` in an `.onAppear` handler on the post itself (and remove the `.onAppear` that you had on the `ScrollView`). You could also add a `print` to help debugging:

```swift
ForEach(viewModel.posts) {post in
    posts_cell(post: post, user: user)
        .onAppear {
            if post.id == selectedpostid {
                print("setting scroll position to id \(post.id)")
                scrollPosition = selectedpostid
            }
        }
}
```